# How to remove disabled date count in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

This is my design code. I'm trying to get date count amount within these days selection. Usually I get date count correctly. But when I select date range within disabled dates I can't get real count. Please help me.

```js
var arrayable = ['2015/07/22', '2015/07/23'];

$('#txtDate1, #txtDate2').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {

    var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
        if ($.inArray(datestring, arrayable) != -1 ) {
             return [false];
         } 
    var weekenddate = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
     return weekenddate; 
    }
});



    $('button').click(function() {
        var start   = $('#txtDate1').datepicker('getDate');
        var end = $('#txtDate2').datepicker('getDate');
        var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
        alert(days);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
From :<input type='text' id='txtDate1' /> <br/>
To :<input type='text' id='txtDate2' />
   <br><button>number of days</button>
```

Comment: You can't select the disabled date but you can enter it manually in the text boxes. It seems to work fine and gives the date diference with all the combinations I tried. Here is the jsfiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/man_luck/3jwqyag2/

Comment: I'm sorry your link doesn't show any luck

Comment: what do you mean?? the link didn't work??

Comment: No I tried the preview. When I select dates to 21/07 to 24/07 count is still 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found answer my own. I hope one day this will help to someone. I disabled weekends and specific dates came from an array. After that I removed all selected disable dates count withing selection area.Take look at this jsfiddle.

```js
var arrayable = ['2015-08-25','2015-08-26'];

function disableSpecificDates(date){
 var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    for(var i =0; i<arrayable.length;i++){
     if($.inArray(datestring,arrayable)!=-1){
     return[false];
     }
    }
var weekend= $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return weekend;
}

 $('#txtDate1, #txtDate2').datepicker({
    minDate :0,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay:  disableSpecificDates
 });

   $('button').click(function() {
        var start   = $('#txtDate1').datepicker('getDate');
        var end = $('#txtDate2').datepicker('getDate');
        var totalBusinessDays = 0;
               // normalize both start and end to beginning of the day
        start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        end.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        var current = new Date(start);
        current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
        var day;
        while (current <= end) {
        day = current.getDay();
         var mystring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', current);    
        if (day < 1 || day > 5 || $.inArray(mystring,arrayable)!=-1) {
       
            ++totalBusinessDays;
        }
      current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
        }
 var days   = (((end - start)/1000/60/60/24)-totalBusinessDays);
        
       alert(days);
    });
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

From :<input type='text' id='txtDate1' /> <br/>
To :<input type='text' id='txtDate2' />
   <br><button>number of days</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function which could tell you if a date is disabled in the datepicker. But you can add the function defined here; http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7279#comment:5 to jquery-ui.js.

Iterate through the dates and increment the counter only if the date is enabled. The usage is defined here; https://forum.jquery.com/topic/check-whether-a-ui-datepicker-date-is-disabled